# how would i put this in the main()?

Tags: python, function, parameters, return

I have a coding assignment that needs the following:

Add a main() function to remove all code from global space

Add at least 1 function that gets called from the main function.

At least 1 function must take and use parameters

At least 1 function must return a value that your program uses

and this is what I have so far

```
color = str(input("What color turtle was drawing the shapes? ")).lower()
numofshapes = int(input("how many shapes did it draw? ")).lower()

def whatturtle(color,numofshapes):
    if color != "orange":
        answer1 = "you are colorblind"
    elif color != "blue":
        answer1 = "his name is leonardo"
    elif numofshapes != 5:
        answer2 = "he did not draw that amount of shapes"
    elif numofshapes = 5:
        answer2 = "he drew some regular polygons with 3,4,6,9,12 sides!"
return answer1
return answer2

#####
def main():

main()
```

what i am trying to do here is have the user say what was the color of the turtle that was drawing the shapes and how many shapes did it draw (which is blue and 5) i need that function inside the def main(), how would i do that? also the output i am trying to get is the program say "answer1 and answer 2" ( for example, "you are colorblind and he did not draw that amount of shapes" ) please help thank you!

Comment: I have added a better explanation to what I did + fixed the statements to work with strings since int isn't necessary here, + I don't know why you edited your question with a personal one, but you can send me a message via chat :) https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/12291295/user12291295

Answer (score 3):

```
def whatturtle(color, numofshapes):
    answer1, answer2 = '', ''
    if color != "orange":
        answer1 = "you are colorblind"
    elif color != "blue":
        answer1 = "his name is leonardo"
    if numofshapes != '5':
        answer2 = "he did not draw that amount of shapes"
    elif numofshapes == '5':
        answer2 = "he drew some regular polygons with 3,4,6,9,12 sides!"

    return answer1 + answer2


#####
def main():
  color = input("What color turtle was drawing the shapes? ").lower()
  numofshapes = input("how many shapes did it draw? ")
  print(whatturtle(color, numofshapes))


main()
```

input:

```
What color turtle was drawing the shapes? blue
how many shapes did it draw? 6
```

output:

```
you are colorblindhe did not draw that amount of shapes
```

You had some syntax errors, redundant code and un-reachable `return` statement;

- If `color` did match, since everything was in `elif` statements it would never reach the conditions of `answer2`, so I added an `if` is more suitable in the 3rd condition.
- The 4rd condition was `numofshapes = 5` which is not really a condition but an assignment operator which returns a `syntax error`, an equality condition is written like this: `==`.
- The 2nd return `return answer2` was unreachable since you returned `answer` already, in Python you can return more than 1 statement and I concatenated them with the `+` operator which is one of its functionalities for strings.
- You tried to `.lower()` an `int` when inputting `numofshapes`, `.lower()` works on strings.